# Is there any way to shortcut repetitive functions in JS?

Tags: javascript, dry

I am currently experimenting with JS and I made this code, the purpose of which is pretty self-explainatory:

```js
const DAYS_IN_JULY = 31;
const DAYS_IN_APRIL = 30;
const DAYS_IN_FEBUARY = 28;
console.log('Days in July:', DAYS_IN_JULY);
console.log('Hours in July:', DAYS_IN_JULY * 24);
console.log('Minutes in July:', DAYS_IN_JULY * 24 * 60);
console.log('Seconds in July:', DAYS_IN_JULY * 24 * 60 * 60);
console.log('Days in April:', DAYS_IN_APRIL);
console.log('Hours in April:', DAYS_IN_APRIL * 24);
console.log('Minutes in April:', DAYS_IN_APRIL * 24 * 60);
console.log('Seconds in April:', DAYS_IN_APRIL * 24 * 60 * 60);
console.log('Days in Febuary:', DAYS_IN_FEBUARY);
console.log('Hours in Febuary:', DAYS_IN_FEBUARY * 24);
console.log('Minutes in Febuary:', DAYS_IN_FEBUARY * 24 * 60);
console.log('Seconds in Febuary:', DAYS_IN_FEBUARY * 24 * 60 * 60);
```

Is there any way to shorten the amount of lines here?

I tried to do something with arrays and for() loop, but it didn't work.

Comment: use a lookup table and loops

Comment: Make a function to print a month that takes name and number of days

Comment: @le3th4x0rbot the what

Comment: Use an object like `days_in_month = {july: 31, april: 30, february: 28}`. Then loop over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use arrays and loops to shorten your code. Here is an example:

```
const months = [
  { name: 'July', days: 31 },
  { name: 'April', days: 30 },
  { name: 'February', days: 28 }
];

for (const month of months) {
  console.log(`Days in ${month.name}:`, month.days);
  console.log(`Hours in ${month.name}:`, month.days * 24);
  console.log(`Minutes in ${month.name}:`, month.days * 24 * 60);
  console.log(`Seconds in ${month.name}:`, month.days * 24 * 60 * 60);
}
```

In this code, we define an array of objects, where each object represents a month with its name and number of days. We then use a for-of loop to iterate over each month object in the array and output the desired information for each month. The string template literal notation ${month.name} is used to insert the name of each month into the output.

Comment: Did you generate this using chatGPT?

Comment: I have a question - in the `for` there is a keyword `month`. Can all occurrences of it just be changed to anything, e.g. `i`?

Comment: @0stone0 this question is very old, generating answers with gpt wasn't really a thing back then, so probably not